# ORA-00932 on Oracle function with a UDT

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function, but I am getting the following error.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
12/3     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
12/18    PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER
```

The code is:

```
CREATE TYPE join_t IS OBJECT (
   inn     NUMBER(38),
   out     NUMBER(38)
);
/

CREATE TYPE join_jt IS TABLE OF join_t;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION knn_join RETURN number
IS
    CURSOR cur_fv_table IS SELECT id,fv FROM londonfv WHERE id <= 3000;

    retval join_jt := join_jt ();
    var_fv londonfv.fv%type;
    var_id londonfv.id%type;
    join_table join_jt := join_jt();
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_fv_table;
    LOOP
        FETCH cur_fv_table INTO var_id,var_fv;
        SELECT join_jt(r.id, var_id) BULK COLLECT INTO join_table
        FROM   londonfv r
        WHERE  manhattan_dist(r.fv,var_fv) <= 5;
    END LOOP;           
END;
/
```

Londonfv table >>

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
PHOTOID                                            VARCHAR2(10)
FV                                                 BLOB
```

How can I solve this?

It is running on Oracle 11g.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE londonfv (
 ID      NUMBER(38) NOT NULL,
 PHOTOID VARCHAR2(10),
 FV      BLOB
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE join_t IS OBJECT (
   inn  NUMBER(38),
   out  NUMBER(38)
);
/

CREATE TYPE join_jt IS TABLE OF join_t;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION manhattan_dist(
  fv1 LONDONFV.FV%TYPE,
  fv2 LONDONFV.FV%TYPE
) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 0;                              -- Implement this.
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION knn_join RETURN number
IS
  join_table join_jt;                    -- You don't need to initialise this BULK COLLECT will.
BEGIN
  SELECT join_t( b.id, a.id )            -- JOIN_T not JOIN_JT
  BULK COLLECT INTO join_table
  FROM   londonfv a
         INNER JOIN
         londonfv b
         ON ( manhattan_dist(a.fv,b.fv) <= 5 )
  WHERE  a.id <= 3000;

  RETURN 0;
END;
/
```

Comment: Got the same error for your function, mate:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/3  PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/24  PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got
  BLOB

Comment: This one worked, though...

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION knn_join RETURN number
IS
CURSOR cur_fv_table IS SELECT id,fv FROM londonfv WHERE id <= 3000;
retval join_jt := join_jt ();
var_fv londonfv.fv%type;
var_id londonfv.id%type;
join_table join_jt := join_jt();
BEGIN
 OPEN cur_fv_table;
 LOOP
  FETCH cur_fv_table INTO var_id,var_fv;
  SELECT join_t(r.id, var_id) BULK COLLECT INTO join_table FROM londonfv r  ;
 END LOOP;   
END;
/

Thanks for your tips...

Comment: @Siqueira Updated - your function will not work as you intend as each iteration of the loop the `join_table` will be re-initialised to an empty collection and then re-populated for that iteration before the next iteration clears it again. `BULK COLLECT INTO` does not append but instead replaces the contents.

Comment: I do know that.

The function does not make sense yet because it is unfinished.

Comment: I intend to gather the answers into the retval table... and return it.

Comment: I cannot use the manhattan_dist function like this manhattan_dist(a.fv,b.fv) anyway (this is the reason I am building this function).